# Define the function $g: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by the rule $g((m,n)) = (2^n)(3^m)$. Prove one to one

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For this one you can also provide a counter example but I could not come up with one. So I started to set up a proof to it but I realized after a bit of algebraic steps I found out that I have 4 variables in my equation that I need to prove are always equal. For example,

$n_1 = n_2$

and

$m_1 = m_2$

But of course I can't do that in one equation so I am kind of lost on how to prove one-to-one on this one. OR if there is a counter-example that I have overlooked. 
Edit: Yes one-to-one is injective

Comment: It's a consequence of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.  What are your assumptions exactly?

Comment: Is one to one in the question means injective !

Comment: Everything I put on this page is what I know. I think there is a counter example because while I was doing my proof I ended at ((ln(2))(n1-n2) = ((ln3))(m2-m1). I feel like this would show me that there HAS to be a counter example right?

Comment: You aren't going to find a counter-example

Answer (score 1):

So, a one-to-one function is basically a function which doesn't map distinct elements in the domain ($\mathbb{N}$ $\times$ $\mathbb{N}$ in our case) to the same element in the range ($\mathbb{N}$ in our case). Mathematically, this translates to

$g(m_{1}$,$n_{1})$ = $g(m_{2}$,$n_{2})$ $\Rightarrow$ ($m_{1}$,$n_{1}$) = ($m_{2}$,$n_{2}$ ).

So, assuming the above, we get the equation ($2^{n_{1}}$)($3^{m_{1}}$) = ($2^{n_{2}}$)($3^{m_{2}}$)  $\Rightarrow$ ($2^{n_{1}- n_{2} }$) = ($3^{m_{2}- m_{1} }$) `(and you can divide by the powers of 2,3 since they are never going to be 0)` and then its straightforward to show that the only case when the above equation is satisfied is when $n_{1}$ = $n_{2}$ and $m_{1}$ = $m_{2}$.

Hence, proving your claim.